# Firebase notifications: activity doesn't launch when status bar notification is clicked

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently experiencing the following problem:

1. I've implemented custom FirebaseMessagingService and the method onMessageReceived() is overriden. Also when the app is in background i get the bundle from getExtras().
2. I need the notification content in order to save it locally in db.

What happens:

1. Send 3 notifications from Firebase console when the app is in background
2. 3 status bar notifications are created.
3. Click on one of them -> launcher activity is opened and the content from the notification is saved.
4. Click on the other status bar notifications (when the app is still in foreground) -> nothing happens...

Could you please help?

Launcher Activity code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String title = (String) extras.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_TITLE);
        String imageUrl = (String) extras.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_IMAGE_URL);
        String url = (String) extras.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_URL);
        String description = (String) extras.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_DESCRIPTION);
        Long sentTime = (Long) extras.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_SENT_TIME);

        if (Util.isStringsNotNull(description)) {
            News news = new News();
            news.setTitle(title);
            news.setMessage(description);
            news.setDescription(description);
            news.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
            news.setUrl(url);
            news.setDate(sentTime);
            news.save();

            EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnNewsUpdatedEvent(news));
            AppPreferences.incrementUnseenNewsCount(this);
        }
    }

    String action = getIntent().getAction();

    if (Util.isStringNotNull(action) && action.equals(ACTION_SEARCH)) {
        startActivity(MainActivity.getIntentActionSearch(this));
    } else {
        startActivity(MainActivity.getIntent(this));
    }
```

Custom FirebaseMessagingService code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    LogUtil.log(BASIC_TAG, "onMessageReceived called!");

    String description = null;
    String imageUrl = null;
    String url = null;
    String title = null;

    Map<String, String> dataMap = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (dataMap != null && !dataMap.isEmpty()) {
        description = dataMap.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_DESCRIPTION);
        imageUrl = dataMap.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_IMAGE_URL);
        url = dataMap.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_URL);
        title = dataMap.get(Constants.TOPIC_KEY_TITLE);
    }

    if (Util.isStringNotNull(description)) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

        News news = new News();
        news.setDate(remoteMessage.getSentTime());
        news.setTitle(Util.isStringNotNull(title) ? title : notification.getTitle());
        news.setMessage(notification.getBody());
        news.setDescription(description);
        news.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
        news.setUrl(url);
        news.save();

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnNewsUpdatedEvent(news));
        AppPreferences.incrementUnseenNewsCount(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Ameer, already done!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have your launcher activity code in the onCreate() method of your activity. Once the activity is created and you click another notification the onCreate() will not be called again.

What you need to do to update the activity that is already visible to the user is override the onNewIntent(Intent intent) method of the activity in which the data is displayed and update your views there.

Comment: I've tried your solution. Unfortunately, onNewIntent(Intent intent) method wasn't called (in MainActivity which is the currently visible activity) and nothing happened. Do I have to set a special flag to this activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have no experience with sending messages from the Firebase Console (we're still using GCM) but afaik notifications always have a PendingIntent as ContentIntent if you can open the app by clicking on them. If the app is already in the foreground this will end up in onNewIntent when launched with launch mode singleTop (either through manifest or IntentFlag) and otherwise launches a new Activity on the current Task Stack. Could you provide more information on your launch modes?

Comment: Ok, and what is the getIntent function you just copy pasted? have you overriden that in the Activity?

Comment: I'm getting more and more confused, how is this related to the issue?

Comment: forget it, it's not related.

Comment: Could you update your original question with more information on what you're doing with your Task Stack? The implementation depends largely on what you're trying to achieve there. Could you also update the "launcher activity code" and show where you've implemented that?